# How to set the MIME type on jQuery for Watson Language Translator API?

Tags: jquery, api

I am connecting to Watson Language Translator API with ajax. Basic authentication can pass, so it can check the output of API from the URL output on google chrome console. However, ajax can not read the output result. In the console, the following error also occurs.

"Refused to execute script from 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate?callback=jQuery3210879483874866891_1519969671034&text=Hello%20Wordl&source=en&target=es&_=1519969671035'; because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.  "

The cause is MIME type and I don't know how to change it. If you know the solution, please tell me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>client</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

 $("#btn").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate',
    type:'POST',
    data : {'text': 'Hello Wordl', 'source': 'en', 'target': 'es'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX'}
  })
  .done(function(data){
    console.dir(data);
  })
  .fail(function(data){
    console.dir(data);
  });

 });

});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
<button id="btn">TEST</button>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I accessed the URL of console message "Refused to execute script from.....". There was only "Hola Mundo" of translated "Hello World". The source code of that page is as follows. Also, after downloading the page, it was a text file that name is "translate.txt"

```
<html>
<head>
<style id="style-1-cropbar-clipper">/* Copyright 2014 Evernote Corporation. All rights reserved. */
.en-markup-crop-options {
    top: 18px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -100px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: 2px rgba(255,255,255,.38) solid !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.en-markup-crop-options div div:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">Hola Mundo</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us some data, the ajax call will fetch?

Comment: The issue in your code is, that you pass `dataType: 'jsonp',` but the API is returning a plain text response (`text/plain`).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I accessed the URL of console message "Refused to execute script from.....". There was only "Hola Mundo" of translated "Hello World". The source code is described in the updated part of this question. Also, after downloading the page, it was a text file that name is "translate.txt".

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?curl#translate):

> Set the Accept header to "application/json" to get a JSON response body with word_count and character_count attributes in addition to the translation. By default, the service assumes Accept is "text/plain", and will return the translation as plain text.

According to your example, the default (this must be `text/plain`) is a HTML page. That is most definitely not what you want. Therefore you need to tell the remote endpoint, you want a JSON response (see `Accept` header in code block).

The resulting JSON object looks like this (sample from docs):

```
{
  "translations": [{
    "translation": "Hola"
  }],
  "word_count": 1,
  "character_count": 5
}
```

Now you need to tell jQuery, that the answer will be such a JSON object (see `dataType`). Here is the complete code (use `data.translations[0].translation` to get the translation):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
    data: {'text': 'Hello Wordl', 'source': 'en', 'target': 'es'},
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX'}
})
.done(function(data){
    console.dir(data);
    console.log('In spanish:', data.translations[0].translation);
})
.fail(function(data){
    console.dir(data);
});
```